# Why can't I check if an environment variable is undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

This test is printing out `fine!!!!`.  Why isn't it printing out `UNDEFINED!!!!`?

```
describe('process test', () => {
    require('dotenv').config()

    it('will make a call from the athena library to get data', async () => {
        process.env["FOO"] = undefined

        const foo: string | undefined = process.env["FOO"]

        if (foo === undefined) {
            console.log('UNDEFINED!!!!')
        } else {
            console.log('fine!!!!')
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: because of this line: `process.env["FOO"] = undefined`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documenation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_env) says

> Assigning a property on process.env will implicitly convert the value to a string.

```
process.env.test = null;
console.log(process.env.test);
// => 'null'
process.env.test = undefined;
console.log(process.env.test);
// => 'undefined'
```

Which is kind of expected because in reality the environment can store only strings. 
Assigning `undefined` will not delete the environment variable, again the documentation says

> Use delete to delete a property from process.env.

```
process.env.TEST = 1;
delete process.env.TEST;
console.log(process.env.TEST);
// => undefined
```